# For a fixed degree, is there always a Lagrange polynomial below the original function?

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

Let $x_1<x_2< \ldots <x_n$ be $n$ real numbers, and let $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$
be real values to be interpolated. Let $r\leq n$. For any $I\subseteq 
\lbrace 1,2,\ldots,n\rbrace$ of cardinality $r$, we may form the Lagrange
polynomial $L_I$ from the pairs $(x_i,y_i)_{i\in I}$ ; this will be the unique
polynomial of degree $<r$ such that $L_I(x_i)=y_i$ for any $i\in I$.

Is it always the case that at least one of these $L_I$ satisfies
 $L_I(x_j) \leq y_j$ for any $j$ ? This can be seen to be true
 in the “small” cases $r=1,2$ or $n$.

Remark : geometrically, the $r=2$ case means  that for any finite collection of points in the plane, there will be a straight line passing through two of those points and staying below all the other points. This will be a “lower” edge of the convex hull of the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work, by induction on $r$ :

For $r=1$ we have to pick $I_1 = \{i_1\}$ where $y_{i_1} = \min \{ y_1 \ldots y_n\}$, and $L_{I_1} = y_{i_1}$.

Suppose you have a subset $I_r$ of size $r$ and a polynomial $L_{I_r}$ passing through $(x_i,y_i)$ for $i \in I_r$ and for which $L_{I_r}(x_j) \le y_j$ for $y \notin I_r$. We have to add to $L_{I_r}$ a polynomial of the form $\lambda \prod_{i \in I_r}(x-x_i)$. We pick the smallest $|\lambda|$ that meets another point : for each $(x_j,y_j)$ we compute $\lambda_j = (y_j - L_{I_r}(x_j))/\prod_{i \in I_r} (x_j-x_i)$. We pick the $i_{r+1}$ that minimizes $|\lambda_{i_{r+1}}|$, then $I_{r+1} = I \cup \{i_{r+1}\}$, and $L_{I_{r+1}} = L_{I_r} + \lambda_{i_{r+1}} \prod_{i \in I_r} (x-x_i)$

Comment: @EwanDelanoy : with those three points you get $I_1 = \{1\}, L_{I_1} = 1$ that meets $(1,1)$ and is below $(2,2)$ and $(5,3)$ ; $I_2 = \{1;3\}, L_{I_2} = 1+(x-1)/2 = (x+1)/2$ that meets $(1,1)$ and $(5,3)$ and is below $(2,2)$ , and finally $I_3 = \{1;2;3\}$ and $L_3$ is the Lagrange polynomial interpolating the three points.

Comment: you’re right, I was wrong, I just deleted my comment.

Comment: If we put $Q(x)=\prod_{i\in I_r}(x-x_i)$, then for any point $(x,y)$
to be interpolated and for $k=i_{r+1}$, we have
$|y-L_{I_r}(x)| \geq \big| (y_k-L_{I_r}(x_k))\frac{Q(x)}{Q(x_k)}\big|$.
Now $y-L_{I_r}(x)$ is nonnegative by the induction hypothesis, so we can rewrite 
this as $y-L_{I_r}(x) \geq \big| (y_k-L_{I_r}(x_k))\frac{Q(x)}{Q(x_k)}\big|
\geq (y_k-L_{I_r}(x_k))\frac{Q(x)}{Q(x_k)}$, or in other words
$y\geq L_{I_{r+1}}(x)$ as wished.